# Windows Server having problems keeping my session after the next page load

Tags: php, session, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm going to share my basic configuration with hopes that somebody can clue in onto where my problem lies with my session variables.  The sessions are not saving in-between page loads, and for the life of my I cannot decide why.

This is my first Windows PHP application that I'm building, so I'm at a loss right now after having tried everything I can think of.

The session save path IS WRITABLE.  Verified using this code:

```
if (!is_writable(session_save_path()) ) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
}
```

The `session.cookie_domain` is blank (not set to anything).  Again, this is correct based on my experience.

I'm using [ToroPHP](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP) as my simple router.  For my test, I simply route to a very simple class.  You'll see it below.

Here is my Web.Config file.  This is what allows me to use [ToroPHP](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Toro" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
            <compilation debug="true"/>
        </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is my configuration script, it's the very first thing called (besides setting my $ABS_SITE_PATH var):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//SET TIMEZONE
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

    $expireTime = 60 * 60 * 7 * 20; // 20 week expire time: seconds, minutes, days, weeks.
    ini_set('session.save_path', $ABS_SITE_PATH.'/sess');
    session_set_cookie_params($expireTime,"/",NULL, TRUE, TRUE);
    session_start();
```

And here is my simple test I'm performing:

```
class sessionTestHandler{
    public function get()
    {

        if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
          $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
        } else {
          $_SESSION['count']++;
        }
        var_dump($_SESSION['count']);
    }
}
```

I get `int(0)` output to my screen on every page load, no matter what.  If I var_dump the entire session variable, I get:  `array(1) { ["count"]=> int(0) }`

If any additional information is needed I'll be happy to provide.  Thanks.

UPDATE:
This is across all browsers.

UPDATE 1/14:
On every page load, I am outputting `session_id();` and it shows a different ID on every load.  So the session ID is not persistent between page loads.

Comment: you checked the session cookie in your browser?

Comment: Please give a `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: Could you please check the points from my answer and confirm that a) the session was not started before you change the path. b) you use the same session id for subsequent requests.

Comment: Are you sure your `sessionTestHandler` code is running after `session_start()`? You can check `session_id()` and if it's a blank string then no session has been started.

Comment: Check privileges to session folder, try use wincache session handler

Comment: Added info to bottom of the question re: @Jasper.

Comment: @Shackrock Sounds like the server isn't sending the `PHPSESSID` cookie with the response of the HTML document. You can check this with your developer tools. In Chrome, press `F + 12` to open the developer tools, then load the page. Go to the `Network` tab, click on the document and look at the `Cookies` tab on the right. It'll show you all the cookies sent back with the document. If you don't see PHPSESSID then you've got an issue. If this turns out to be the case, I'd back-off of all the custom changes I made to the session cookie handling configuration to see if it works by default.

Comment: @Jasper confirmed, it says "this site has no cookies" ....  Will play with some things to go back to the basics and report back.

Comment: @Shackrock I'd imagine this isn't the case since it's an issue in multiple browsers, but makes sure you aren't blocking cookies in your browser(s). Otherwise, try to set a cookie manually in PHP, `setcookie(...)` and see if it sets a cookie properly.

Comment: No dice.  Answer below in comments was the fix, I was not testing in HTTPS - doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. I'll assume it's an error in the test procedure or a configuration error. As there comes no further information I will present some general advices:

### Set the session save path before the session is started

Changing the session path [should happen before the session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) is started:

> session_save_path() needs to be called before session_start()

You might start the session unintentionally before changing the save path (e.g. [`session.auto_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) or some `session_start()` somewhere in your framework). Double [check](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) that the session was not started! If it was it might be advisable to move application specific runtime configuration into a [.htaccess](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

### Start the session before you access `$_SESSION`

Make sure that your [session is started](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before you access the session for your test case.

### Ensure the propagation of the session id

Check on the browser side that you use for each subsequent request the same session id. You can do this either by checking the session id in the URI or by checking the session cookie. Double check on the server side the result of [`session_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php). **Note that [`session.cookie_secure`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure) <del>can restrict</del> does in your case restrict the session propagation to HTTPS only.** If this is the case, adopt your test procedure to HTTPS or allow the session propagation by a http cookie (e.g. `session_set_cookie_params($expireTime,"/",NULL, FALSE, TRUE);`).

### Compare the expected configuration with `phpinfo()`

You are making some runtime changes to the configuration. There are scenarios where those won't be applied. Compare the output of [`phpinfo()`](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) with your expectations. In your case check each [`session.*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) property.

Comment: Session save path is called before session start.  If I try `session_status();` before `session_start();` - it returned `1`.  That should not happen right?  I certainly don't start the session anywhere else.  `auto_start` is set to OFF.  See updated question for `session_id();` information.  `phpinfo` looks correct on everything I'm setting via PHP.

Comment: status 1 is OK, as it is `PHP_SESSION_NONE`. The propagation of the session id seems to be your problem. Did you check the cookie on the client? Can you please tell us your `session.*` settings?

Comment: Your have `session.cookie_secure = On`. Do you use HTTPS in your test procedure?

Comment: Wow, such an oversight.  That was indeed the problem.  I changed the following line to: session_set_cookie_params($expireTime,"/",NULL, FALSE, TRUE); (since I was not in HTTPS during testing), and all is well.  If you update your answer I will mark it as correct, thank you.